# asterisk dial hangup direction - Is there a variable I can use to record the direction of hangup?

Tags: asterisk, ivr

Is there a variable I can use to record the direction of hangup?

Example:
Calling ----> Called. Called party hangs up. Info I want -->  Release from Called party

Example 2:
Calling ----> Called. Caller hangs up. Info I want -->  Release from Calling party

Answer (score -1):

The **HANGUPCAUSE** variable maybe helps you.